# Is there a way to collect data from all cards from a form to a collection? (Powerapps)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, powerapps-forms

Sorry if this is a bit off topic, I'm currently building a powerapps application that lets the user fill in details for an item using a form, after the user is done inputting the info for each item, we submit the info to a sharepoint list.

The way I'm trying to implement this is the following:

1. Append the info(entries from a form) for each item to a collection.
2. User is complete with entries, presses finish button which appends the entries in the collection to a sharepointlist.

**Problem**

I cant find a way to append all the entries of the form at once, so I have to do something like the following:

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you just do

```
Collect(collection, form.Updates)
```

Comment: You could accept this solution as an Answer and upvote it.